# getelementbyid in Ionic popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, ionic-framework

I'd like to call popup and some js function with one button. I need to change texts in popup with this function. My popup code is:

```
angular.module('starter')
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: '<div id="location-status"></div>',
        template: '<div class="text-center"><ion-spinner icon="ripple" class="spinner-positive"></ion-spinner></div>'
      });
    };
  });
```

Function is simple so far:

```
function writeText() {
  document.getElementById("location-status").innerHTML = "Some text"
}
```

And button:

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-locate" ng-click="showAlert()" onclick="writeText()"></button>
```

It works when my div id="location-status" is somewhere in index.html file. It didn't work in popup. What's wrong?

Comment: does the popup exist at the time writeText() is called? maybe the onclick triggers BEFORE the popup is created/inserted into the dom.

Comment: I've just checked it. It's not that problem. I've called popup with

    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-locate" onclick="writeText()"></button>

in it. Clicking button makes nothing in popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-bind` directive to add an text over there. Use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`

**Code**

```
$scope.showAlert = function() {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: '<div id="location-status" ng-bind="textToBeShown"></div>',
    template: '<div class="text-center"><ion-spinner icon="ripple" class="spinner-positive"></ion-spinner></div>'
  });
};

$scope.writeText = function(){
    $scope.textToBeShown = "Some Text."
}
```

**Update**

`$ionicPopup.alert` returns a promise, you could use `.then` function over it. As you want to access of DOM of alert popup. Inside `.then` function you could have DOM rendered on the page. You could call writeText method from there.

```
$scope.showAlert = function() {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: '<div id="location-status" ng-bind="textToBeShown"></div>',
    template: '<div class="text-center"><ion-spinner icon="ripple" class="spinner-positive"></ion-spinner></div>'
  }).then(function(){
      writeText(); //Native javascript function.
  })
};
```

> I don't encourage you do this, doing DOM manipulation by this way
>   considered as BAD pattern in AngularJS

Comment: Thank You, but my writeText() is just example. I'd like to use bigger function in pure js. My AngularJS knowledge is to small to rewrite it. But if I only can get popup elements by id, I'll be happy. Any idea?

Comment: Still nothing. It still looks, that i just can't getelementbyid.

Comment: @user293761 could you give me plunkr..with what you tried till now

Comment: writeText() works only on `div id="location-status"`, when div is in my index.html file. If div is in popup, it didn't work.

I tried to place button, taht calls writeText() in popup. So i call popup and then try togetelementbyid. Result is the same. If div is in index.html it works. If div is in popup it didn't.

I've tried also your last code. Result is the same.

Comment: Also adding then(function() works. If I add for example console.log, I can see it works. But still can't getelementbyid.

Comment: @user293761 provide me plunkr..so that I can proceed my help..but the thing which you are doing is not a good pattern of doing things with AngularJS

Comment: Sorry. I don't understood, what plunkr is at the first time. Ok. I can provide it to You but... Your advices are really precious to me. Maybe I can bypass the problem and "bad patterns". I asked another question - <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574301/ionic-calling-one-of-3-popups-depending-on-some-variable">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574301/ionic-calling-one-of-3-popups-depending-on-some-variable</a>. Answering it can solve my problems. Thanks for Your time.