# Ionic calling one of 3 popups depending on some variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, ionic-framework

I have 3 popups in my Ionic app;

```
angular.module('starter')
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
    $scope.showAlert1 = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Succes!',
      });
    };
    $scope.showAlert2 = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Fail...',
      });
    };
    $scope.showAlert3 = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Third option',
      });
    };
  });
```

I'd like to assign them to one button. When the button is clicked and

`var x=1` i'd like to call `showAlert1`

`var x=2` i'd like to call `showAlert2`

`var x=3` i'd like to call `showAlert3`

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

My index.html structure:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="list.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="MyApp">
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-locate" ng-click="showAlert()" onclick="writeText()"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <ion-content>
        <ul class="list">
            <!--some list-->
        </ul>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>

    <!--some subpages templates-->

</body>
```

Comment: Please share your template side. That will make things clear.

Comment: I've editet post. is it enough?

Comment: where is value of `var x` getting changed ? and what does `onclick="writeText()"` do, plus do not use ng-click and onclick at same time, if you want to call two function with one click, just do this  ng-click="showAlert(); writeText();".

Answer (score 0):

All of your alerts are same except title (or template, if you are using that option), so instead of calling $ionicPopup.alert() call in separate functions just make one function to call that, and put condition on title and template like this

```
 $scope.showAlert = function() {
      var myTitle = "";
      if(x==1){
        title = "Succes!";
     } else if(x==2){ 
        title = "Fail!"; 
     } else { title = "third option"; }
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: myTitle
      });
  };
```